# How to solve this first order PDE using method of characteristics, cannot find any resources anywhere online.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

The PDE in question is $u_{x}u_{y}=1, u(x,0)=\sqrt{x}$. The process for solving a first order PDE using method of characteristics when the terms are summed is relatively well-established, but I cannot figure out how to generalize this to a first order PDE with the terms multiplied together.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Let me present a solution using the method of separation of variables. Let's assume that $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$; then
\begin{align}
u_xu_y=1 &\implies f'(x)g(y)f(x)g'(y)=1 \\
&\implies f(x)f'(x)=\lambda=\frac{1}{g(y)g'(y)}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is a nonzero constant.
Solving for $f(x)$ we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{2}(f^2(x))'=\lambda\implies f^2(x)=2\lambda x+ a\implies f(x)=\pm\sqrt{2\lambda x+a}\,. \tag{2}
$$
Similarly,
$$
g(y)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2y}{\lambda}+b}\,. \tag{3}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ we obtain
$$
u(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{(2\lambda x + a)\left(\frac{2y}{\lambda}+b\right)}\,. \tag{4}
$$
The condition $u(x,0)=\sqrt{x}$ is satisfied by the positive solution, provided $a=0$ and $b=\frac{1}{2\lambda}$; hence, we finally obtain
$$
u(x,y)=\sqrt{2\lambda x\left(\frac{2y}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)}=\sqrt{4xy+x}\,. \tag{5}
$$